# Is feeding a stray cat bad omen?

Tags: omens

Is feeding stray cats a bad omen? They don't seem to do any harm to me but is it a bad or good omen.

Comment: Have a look at : [What is Bhuta Yajna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33543/20129). It doesn’t explicitly mention cats so it can’t answer your question but still you can have a look.